# VB.Net: Windows Media Player component - The program stop when playing mp4 file

Tags: vb.net, axwindowsmediaplayer

### VB.Net - VisualStudio2017

**Windows Media Player component** - the program close when playing *mp4* file without giving any Error Message.

But works fine when playing *mp3* files.

code:

```
'Not working
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "c:\vid1.mp4"
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play()

'Works fine
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "c:\music.mp3"
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play()
```

Does anyone here know how fix this?

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please tell us the exact error message you get as well as on what line it occurs at in your code.

Comment: It doesn't show any Error message. It just close itself after 4 - 5 seconds.

Comment: I tried it in other computer and now its working. I think the problem is in my machine.

Comment: Check the Windows Event Viewer. It ought to contain additional information if it was a crash.